# Post the text of a Drop down list not the value in PHP

Tags: php, post, html-select

I have this code of a Select in html but i want to send by POST the text.. not the values.. any ideas?? However I do still require the values as well. Thanks in advance!

```
     <select name="calificaciones" id="calificaciones">
         <option selected value="0"> Elige una opción </option>  
         <option value="1">Demoró en terminar</option> 
         <option value="1">Impuntual</option> 
         <option value="2">Grosero(a) en su trato</option>
         <option value="2">Sucio (a) en su trabajo</option>    
         <option value="4">Dejó inconcluso el trabajo</option> 
         <option value="4">No respetó el precio acordado</option> 
         <option value="8">Fue deshonesto (a)</option> 
         <option value="8">Robó</option> 
     </select>
```

Comment: Just put the text as the values as well

Comment: `<option value="Impuntual">Impuntual</option> `

Comment: but i also need that values that's the problem, sorry i didnt explain it very clear

Comment: use some other format for example `<option value="2:Impuntual">Impuntual</option>` then `explode`.

Comment: @u_mulder, why shold this other format is better you think ?

Comment: It sends both value and textual representation.

Comment: What do you need the values for? A javascript function? If they're helpful for your UI coding, you could make up another attribute (you're semi-misusing it either way). `<option data-ineedthisforsomething="1" value="Impuntual">Impuntual</option>

Comment: store the key/values on the server, then use the submitted key to look up the value when the form's submitted.

Comment: Your values doesn't seem unique, hope you are not using those for `ID` or something like that!

Comment: i use the values to grade something, and the Text to post them as comments also... in a diferent place, that0s why i need both... ill try explode.

Comment: @u_mulder, I didn't notice that `OP` need both, I thought he only needs the text, anyways, you are right :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery. Have a look http://jsfiddle.net/whizzzkid/HsKEd/2/

```
<select name="calificaciones" id="calificaciones">
         <option selected value="0"> Elige una opción </option>  
         <option value="1">Demoró en terminar</option> 
         <option value="1">Impuntual</option> 
         <option value="2">Grosero(a) en su trato</option>
         <option value="2">Sucio (a) en su trabajo</option>    
         <option value="4">Dejó inconcluso el trabajo</option> 
         <option value="4">No respetó el precio acordado</option> 
         <option value="8">Fue deshonesto (a)</option> 
         <option value="8">Robó</option> 
     </select>
<div id="output"></div>
```

As simple as .html() refer to the fiddle

```
    /*$('option').each(function(){
    $('#output').append($(this).html() + '<br>');
    console.log($(this).html());
});*/

$('select').bind('change', function(){
    $('#output').html($(this).find(':selected').html() + '<br>');
    console.log($(this).find(':selected').html());
});
```

So you can submit the form by jquery after you have their html values. ALSO DO NOT FORGET TO CHECK YOUR BROWSER'S CONSOLE.

edit 1: even a better code.

Comment: i like this also... i'll give it a try  Thanks!!

Comment: @user2588727 have a look http://jsfiddle.net/whizzzkid/HsKEd/2/ even a better example. makes it much more clear.

Comment: Perfect... really useful!

Answer (score 0):

the only solution using php is to substitute the html value attributes. If you want to keep numeric value on that attribute, the only solution is using jquery to build a post request which grab the text instead of the numeric value on submit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
var calificaciones = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value  +':' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
```

So, if you send `calificaciones` then you can explode it (you already have the idea) into an array using `:` on the server side. If you use `POST` then it should be simply

```
$calificaciones = isset($_POST['calificaciones']) ? explode(':', $_POST['calificaciones']) : null;
```

[**Just a demo**.](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/H8wa8/)